# what the fastest method to loop through a very large number of account in a log in page

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, web, data-structures

I was wonder what if i had 1 million users, how much time will take it to loop every account to check for the username and email if the registration page to check if they are already used or not, or check if the username and password and correct in the log in page, won't it take ages if i do it in a traditional for loop?

Comment: Did you try it?  Doesn't sound like it would take very long.

Comment: If you show some piece of code people may give you some advices. Nevertheless, always remember that *"early optimization is the root of all evil"*. Are you sure you *need* it to be faster ?

Comment: Store it in a hash table, NoSQL DB or RDBMS instead to get you O(logn) or better amortized lookup time.

Comment: A computer can generally compute ~10^8 instruction per seconds, seeing you only have 10^6, so it will be pretty fast

Comment: and if you are working with a database, you may want to try indexing the fields used in the query

Answer (score 1):

Rather than give a detailed technical answer, I will try to give a theoretical illustration of how to address your concerns. What you seem to be saying is this:

> Linear search might be too slow when logging users in.

I imagine what you have in mind is this: a user types in a username and password, clicks a button, and then you loop through a list of username/password combinations and see if there is a matching combination. This takes time that is linear in terms of the number of users in the system; if you have a million users in the system, the loop will take about a thousand times as long as when you just had a thousand users... and if you get a billion users, it will take a thousand times longer over again.

Whether this is a performance problem *in practice* can only be determined through testing and requirements analysis. However, if it is determined to be a problem, then there is a place for theory to come to the rescue.

Imagine one small improvement to our original scheme: rather than storing the username/password combinations in arbitrary order and looking through the whole list each time, imagine storing these combinations in alphabetic order by username. This enables us to use binary search, rather than linear search, to determine whether there exists a matching username:

1. check the middle element in the list
2. if the target element is equal to the middle element, you found a match
3. otherwise, if the target element comes before the middle element, repeat binary search on the left half of the list
4. otherwise, if the target element comes after the middle element, repeat binary search on the right half of the list
5. if you run out of list without finding the target, it's not in the list

The time complexity of this is logarithmic in terms of the number of users in the system: if you go from a thousand users to a million users, the time taken goes up by a factor of roughly ten, rather than one thousand as was the case for linear search. This is already a vast improvement over linear search and for any realistic number of users is probably going to be efficient enough. However, if additional performance testing and requirements analysis determine that it's still too slow, there are other possibilities.

Imagine now creating a large array of username/password pairs and whenever a pair is added to the collection, a function is used to transform the username into a numeric index. The pair is then inserted at that index in the array. Later, when you want to find whether that entry exists, you use the same function to calculate the index, and then check just that index to see if your element is there. If the function that maps the username to indices (called a hash function; the index is called a hash) is perfect - different strings don't map to the same index - then this unambiguously tells you whether your element exists. Notably, under somewhat reasonable assumptions, the time to make this determination is mostly independent from the number of users currently in the system: you can get (amortized) constant time behavior from this scheme, or something reasonably close to it. That means the performance hit from going from a thousand to a million users might be negligible.

This answer does not delve into the ugly real-world minutia of implementing these ideas in a production system. However, real world systems to implement these ideas (and many more) for precisely the kind of situation presented.

EDIT: comments asked for some pointers on actually implementing a hash table in Python. Here are some thoughts on that.

So there is a built-in `hash()` function that can be made to work if you disable the security feature that causes it to produce different hashes for different executions of the program. Otherwise, you can `import hashlib` and use some hash function there and convert the output to an integer using e.g. `int.from_bytes`. Once you get your number, you can take the modulus (or remainder after division, using the `%` operator) w.r.t. the capacity of your hash table. This gives you the index in the hash table where the item gets put. If you find there's already an item there - i.e. the assumption we made in theory that the hash function is perfect turns out to be incorrect - then you need a strategy. Two strategies for handling collisions like this are:

1. Instead of putting items at each index in the table, put a linked list of items. Add items to the linked list at the index computed by the hash function, and look for them there when doing the search.
2. Modify the index using some deterministic method (e.g., squaring and taking the modulus) up to some fixed number of times, to see if a backup spot can easily be found. Then, when searching, if you do not find the value you expected at the index computed by the hash method, check the next backup, and so on. Ultimately, you must fall back to something like method 1 in the worst case, though, since this process could fail indefinitely.

As for how large to make the capacity of the table: I'd recommend studying recommendations but intuitively it seems like creating it larger than necessary by some constant multiplicative factor is the best bet generally speaking. Once the hash table begins to fill up, this can be detected and the capacity expanded (all hashes will have to be recomputed and items re-inserted at their new positions - a costly operation, but if you increase capacity in a multiplicative fashion then I imagine this will not be too frequent an issue).

Comment: i fully understoud the theoretical side, but i cant do the technical can you help me pls

Comment: i can transform the username into numbers but i dont know how to make the index of that number equl the number lik list = [...,256,..], list.index(256) = 256, idk how to do this, what about the out of range error.

Comment: @ahmedhassaine updating answer with some python-specific implementation details.